# Why Column Vector is used to Represent Qubit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, notation, linear-algebra

While going through the basics of (quantum computing) and postulates of quantum mechanics
As per the definitions *qubits were represented as Column Vectors and not row Vectors!*

What is the reason we are not using row vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can represent statevectors either as row or column vectors. It is convenient to think of quantum operators as matrices. It is more natural to apply operators from the left to a statevector on the right. In conventional math this is done with column vectors. Row vectors are usually reserved to the dual space. Wikipedia has a section on it in [bra–ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).

In the language of qubits, the state is written as

$$|\psi\rangle= \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are complex numbers. A quantum gate (an operator that acts on a qubit and changes its states) can be written as

$$U= \begin{bmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
with $a,b,c,d$ complex too.

The resulting state, from the action of $U$ over $|\psi\rangle$ is written as

$$|\psi'\rangle =U|\psi\rangle=\begin{bmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} $$

To carry out that operation you use the standard matrix algebra. In the case of quantum mechanics $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ for normalization and $U$ has to be a [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). For more on dual spaces check [What is the physical significance of the Dual Space in QM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281635/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-the-dual-space-in-qm/281654#281654).

For a basic introduction to quantum mechanics you can check any book on the subject. For a rightaway introduction to quantum computing, check these slides from CERN: https://indico.cern.ch/event/970909/attachments/2165159/3654057/PIQC%20Lecture%207.pdf

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you pls give some details/examples on the operators on the state vector to which you are referring here?  Also about the dual space. Just started learning from the basics so need to understand every key definition.

Comment: @Jayendran I added EVEN more but any introduction to quantum information out there will cover this topic right away in the very beginning.